# Need simple jquery autocomplete combobox with struts

Tags: combobox, jquery-autocomplete, struts-1

I want to create a simple jquery autocomplete combobox.
To load combobox data I use struts1 action.

Br,
Med Baba

Comment: Do you have some code? Did you try something?

Comment: no i see some examples in jquery web site but still complicated. finally i used dhtmlxCombo is more easy.